# Why won't my contact form work? the loading.gif is stuck and nothing happens

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have tried using my contact form with XAMPP i have configured .ini files etc. correctly to GMAIL for testing purposes. Can you see where I have made a mistake?

I have even tried WAMP and still nothing works.

I changed the xwamp files as this guy suggested:
[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="contact-form.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/> 
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>  
        <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"/> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> 
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

JS

```
 $('#contactform').submit(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    $("#message").slideUp(250,function() {
        $('#message').hide();
        $('#submit')
            .after('<img src="img/assets/cbp-loading.gif" class="loader" />')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');
        $.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            comments: $('#comments').val(),
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown(250);
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp(850, 'easeInOutExpo');
            }
        );
    });
    return false;
```

PHP

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    mail('myemail@gmail.com', $name, $email, $subject, $message);
}
?>
```

Sendmail code (i have removed the email and password obviously)

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=MYEMAIL@gmail.com
auth_password=MY EMAIL PASSWORD
force_sender=MYEMAIL@gmail.com
```

Comment: Where's your `mail()` function?

Comment: something I must have missed, I'm new to php, where should I add this, :z

Comment: That's the function that does the actual send, so it needs to go after you set your body, subject, etc. More information can be found [https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php](in the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

One of the most underestimated points is to no start XAMPP as administrator. In addition I'm missing some configuartions for smtp and co:

```html
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'EMAIL',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD'
    ));
```

Those are necessary to be allowed to sent to your email adress. If not anyone could spam your email adress.

Sincerely liqSTAR

Comment: where should i copy this to? thnaks

Comment: As already mentioned from other people you are fully missing php. Javascript is just the way to parse and collect the informations from the forms. PHP is the one who will send this informations via email. I'm using "phpmailer". [link](http://www.tutscorner.com/php-tutorials-create-a-contact-form-using-html-and-php-with-a-gmail-address/)

Comment: the php is working, i was missing a curely brace, Now the laoding.gif starts and stops,

Comment: The loading.gif appears, then nothing, this appeard:
unexpected end of file, line 10,

Comment: I fixed it, curly brace was missing,

Comment: Could you please add your full php file. But please be aware to replace "sensible" datas like passwords.

Comment: <?php
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
  $to = 'JUSTREMOVEDIT@gmail.com'; 
  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
        mail('JUSTREMOVEDIT@gmail.com', $name, $email, $subject, $message);
    }
?>

Comment: Please edit your starting post and put it in code-style. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no `mail()` function in the PHP code.

Would recommend stripping back to the simplest test case to start with. As a first test I would recommend writing a simple PHP file that just utilises the `mail()` function to send an email to your own address and returns the result (be sure to also check the PHP error log) - this will help to confirm PHP is configured with a working SMTP server.

I'd then try the form submission without the use of JavaScript to ensure that it's submitting okay. Does the `$.post` action appear in the console okay? Does it show anything as the response or status code?

Comment: I have added my mail() function: I will try and see what he outcome is, Ill check the console now

Comment: the console says, fails to load php file

Comment: Now it says, 
yntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\contact-form.php on line 11

Comment: able to post contact-form.php in full?